# SQL 2012 Integration Services installation

Tags: sql-server-2012

Can you please suggest me the EXE to install SQL integration and Analysis services
I have installed
SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe, SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe from MSDN site.however, I could not find the integration services in my SQL SERVER configuration manager.

Answer (score 1):

These are options of the main SQL Server installer.

[image]

(Image from [this MSDN blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/psssql/2008/09/02/sql-server-2008-management-tools-basic-vs-complete-explained/).)

Analysis Services is the fourth item from the top under Instance Features.  Integration Services is the third item down under Shared Features.

Comment: You might check here for the SQL Server 2012 screen shot since the post is tagged SQL Server 2012... http://www.azurecurve.co.uk/images/posts/2012/09/How_To_Install_SQL_Server_2012/How_To_Install_SQL_Server_2012_9.png